# Laravel Nova: How to set the details of the record to be displayed in the popup below the row when clicked

Tags: datatable, row, responsive, laravel-nova

It is also necessary to foresee collapsing when clicking again on the same line, now, I am engaged in the development of this functionality. I will be very grateful for your help!
For example:
[Example popup details of row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2MVQ.png)
This will improve the adaptability of the table to view the details of the record without losing sight of the current row.